# Docker Letsencrypt ACME server error but why?

Tags: docker, nginx

I am running some atlassian apps in my containers. Everything works fine except the letsencrypt:

It returns an error message :

> Debugging tips: -v improves output verbosity. Help is available under
>   --help.
>
> /app
>
> /etc/nginx/certs/.../app
>
> Creating/renewal ... certificates...
>
> 2019-06-09 10:27:34,332:INFO:simp_le:1382: Generating new account key
>
> ACME server returned an error: urn:acme:error:rateLimited :: There
>   were too many requests of a given type :: Error creating new
>   registration :: too many registrations for this IP

When I try to call the website with https it returns:

> 500 Internal Server Error nginx/1.17.0

When I try to call the website with http it is working:

So the websites has no ssl certificate?
But why? 
I have tried to rebuild everything several times but nothing works for me.
Does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For letsencrypt the error explains that you have tried to generate certificat multiple times without success,it's just a matter of time.

for error 500 you can refer to your NGINX log with:

> tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Or custom log you have on you nginx config

Hope it helps